# Passing sets and optional parameters to a stored procedure T-SQL - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, stored-procedures, set, optional-parameters

I have an **aspx page** with the following controls: **TextBox, CheckBoxList, DropDownList**.
They are used to specify search criteria. The records are taken from **SQL Server Data Base** using a stored procedure.

1. Each **CheckBox** in **CheckBoxList** has a value which is actual ID of a Product Group in the database. If more than one checkbox is selected, how to pass the list of IDs to a stored procedure as a set so I could use **IN @IdList**? What variable types should I use in C# and T-SQL? Is it possible at all?
2. **DropDownList**'s first item is "ALL". When "ALL" is selected, I need to pass something like **NULL** to the stored procedure. How to make the stored procedure to ignore a parameter if it is **NULL**?

   CREATE PROCEDURE FilterList
   @ProductName nvarchar(200),
   @ProductGroupID int
   AS BEGIN
   SELECT
   prod_id AS 'ID',
   prod_name AS 'Name'
   FROM
   dbo.Products
   WHERE
   prod_group_id = @ProductGroupID OR
   prod_name = @ProductName
   END

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve optional parameters in T-SQL stored procedures by having default values equal NULL.

Example where NULL is used as "ignore this parameter":

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dcspFilterEmpList]
    @ProductName nvarchar(200) = null,
    @ProductGroupID int = null
AS BEGIN 

    SELECT
    prod_id AS 'ID',
    prod_name AS 'Name'
    FROM dbo.Products

    WHERE (prod_group_id = @ProductGroupID OR @ProductGroupID IS NULL)
    AND (prod_name = @ProductName OR @ProductName IS NULL)

END
```

It's perfectly fine to define a stored procedure to take a table-valued parameter in T-SQL.
Here is an article on the subject http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/passing-multipledynamic-values-to-stored-procedures-functions-part4-by-using-tvp/

If you need more info on this google for "table-valued parameter"

Example using multi-valued parameters:

```
CREATE TYPE XTV_ProductNames AS TABLE  --extension, table valued == XTV
( ProductName nvarchar(50))
GO
CREATE TYPE XTV_ProductGroups AS TABLE  --extension, table valued == XTV
( ProductGroupID int))
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dcspFilterEmpList]
    @TVP1 XTV_ProductNames READONLY
    ,@TVP2 XTV_ProductGroups READONLY
AS BEGIN 
    SELECT
    prod_id AS 'ID',
    prod_name AS 'Name'
    FROM dbo.Products as p
    INNER JOIN @TVP1 as s
        ON p.prod_name = s.ProductName
    UNION
    SELECT
    prod_id AS 'ID',
    prod_name AS 'Name'
    FROM dbo.Products as p
    INNER JOIN @TVP2 as s
        ON p.prod_group_id = s.ProductGroupID
END
```

Comment: Happy to hear it. Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

Your answer was correct David, but it was a little misleading because the parameter equaling NULL does not make it optional; it just has to be set to any value period.  This also creates optional parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dcspFilterEmpList]
    @ProductName nvarchar(200) = 'DefaultProduct',
    @ProductGroupID int = 1
AS
```

Which could thus be executed without passing any parameters, i.e.:

```
EXEC [dbo].[dcspFilterEmpList]
```

I understand that this wasn't necessarily what Piscovetz was trying to do, but it seems to match more closely the actual topic question shown, and it is an important distinction.

Comment: As I understand it now with your help is that if the procedure sets the value, that makes it optional when called. Whether NULL or some value doesn't matter as long as it gets set in the procedure definition?

Comment: @DavidSöderlund: Yes.